# R Markdown - no ODT and LaTeX options as an output

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, odt

I found [R markdown/knitr](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) useful tool to document my work and generate summary document.

I work with .Rmd (R markdown) files in [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/).
It seems that [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pandoc/) provide appropriate functionality to generate .odt (Open Document Text) and .tex (LaTeX) documents from .Rmd.

However, R studio allows to choose .docx, .html and .pdf formats only.

[image: R Markdown output formats in RStudio]

[image: New R Markdown wizard in RStudio]

I would like to avoid MS Word format since I prefer open standards and working under Linux.

Is it possible to add .odt and .tex options to Rstudio menu?

Comment: How about asking directly to RStudio: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with using HTML, which is in theory an OS-independent format?  Or could you consider converting between PDF and LaTEX format?

Comment: The “pdf” option *is* LaTeX. Simply ensure in the options that the intermediate .tex file isn’t deleted.

Comment: @Pascal I received response from R Studio: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207639177-Add-odt-and-tex-as-output-options-from-R-Markdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to output odt directly in RStudio, but you can always use `knitr::knit` to produce a markdown document and pandoc to produce the odt:

```
library(knitr)
knit("myDoc.Rmd")
system("pandoc myDoc.md -o myDoc.odt")
```

You may have to adjust the pandoc options and adapt the template to get a nice looking result.

As for latex, you can keep the tex sources when compiling to pdf with the following option in your yaml front matter:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---
```